# Simple Facebook App With Php Sdk

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I just need simple and working facebook app. I bought ssl for this and i dont want too much expenses.

If user allowed app it will write his name and gender and his/her friends gender.

my app doesnt redirect after user allow the app. I cant fix it so just need basic app with out url redirecting.

ı used this code but it doesnt work. it need to be corrected:

```
require_once("facebook.php");
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '***',
    'secret' => '***',
  'scope'  => 'manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream,user_photos'
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

Comment: what you say if your app is automatically get user name and gender ??

Comment: @chris sorry, its my mistake. but there is no satisfied answer yet to my questions.

Comment: Understandable, but the responsibility is on you to correct that. You can try rewording your question, providing additional information, etc. If the answers aren't quite there, ask the authors for additional information or if there's anything they need from you to provide a better answer. You can also post a bounty on your question after a couple of days to encourage more and higher quality answers.

Comment: also ı dont know how to use stackoverflow, ı am new, noob on using stackof. for example: ı dont know what "post a bounty on your question" means.

Comment: @TurgutDursun you shoul read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is the simple one page application full fills your needs**

make the file with name ***index.php***

download the facebook library [download here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)

```
<?php 

require_once 'library/facebook.php';


// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'appid',
  'secret' => 'secret',
  'cookie' => true,
)); 

     $app_id = 'appid';

     $canvas_page = "canvas_page_link";


     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . ("&scope=email,read_stream&response_type=token");

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {

     //getting the userid and some other data for verification 

     //get the user id 
            $UserId = $data["user_id"];
            echo 'UserId;' . $UserId;

    //get the user access token
            $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
            echo "</br>" . 'Access_Token:' . $token;

    //set default access token and profile
            $facebook->setAccessToken($token);
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

     //get the user name 
            $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
            $user_name = $user_profile['name'];
            echo "Name: " . $user_name;
            $user_gender = $user_profile['gender'];
            echo "Gender: " . $user_gender;

} 
?>
```

Comment: its not working.

    https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fdev%2Fmyapp%2F&scope=email%2Cread_stream%2Cabout_me&response_type=token

Comment: -there is an error pls try again later.

link become this: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fdev%2Fmyapp%2F&scope=email%2Cread_stream%2Cabout_me&response_type=token

Comment: copy and paste the code in index.php completely and make some necessary changes